# Functional approaches to designing the discrete side of hybrid systems

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state-machine, robotics, control-theory

I'm working on developing controllers for hybrid systems in Haskell.

FRP libraries (right now I'm using [netwire](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire), but there are several good ones and a lot of interesting research on future ones) provide a great solution for the continuous-time side of the problem. Augmenting them with signal names, dimensions, preferred units, and so forth gets you a system that has modularity, is self-describing, and has a straightforward path to confidence in correctness.

I'm looking for information, folklore, or papers that provide similar properties for the discrete-time side. In some sense the problem is much easier, state machines are well-studied and simple. In other senses it's more difficult, I'll briefly explain how.

Correctness is obviously the most important thing, and thankfully it's also straightforward.

Self-description is more of a problem. You'd like the controller not just to be in the correct state, but to be capable of telling you what state it's in. Also how it got there. And where it might go next. So you can tack names on to everything, and it works, but it conflicts somewhat with modularity. You'd also like to be able to build complex discrete time behaviors from simpler ones. But when you ask the system what state it's in, generally the high-level answer is more interesting (or at least, as interesting) as the low level answer. How do you get this cleanly? I've tried a few naive approaches and have wrapped myself in spaghetti a few different ways, but it seems like there must be elegant solutions?

Another problem I've had with self-description is that I'd like to have a list of self-describing conditions (generally comparisons: has it been 10 seconds? am I within 3 feet of the next waypoint? has the battery power fallen below 15%? etc) that are being monitored which might trigger the next state transition. There are tricky questions of what even are the desirable semantics here, since it seems like some of these events are better handled "from the bottom up" (e.g. expected termination conditions of whatever low level step you are performing) and some "from the top down" (e.g. equipment failure detection, geofencing, ...). This can lead to spaghetti of its own even if you relax the goal of self-description.

In addition to diagnostics, accurate self-description information here could also be very useful for abstract interpretation, projecting the state of the system into the future by guessing which events are likely to occur when. Many of the event conditions lead themselves to fairly simple guesses (e.g. using velocity made good, fuel consumption rate, timers). Others are more complicated but might still be worth the effort to develop projections for some applications (e.g. expected orders from operators, weather forecasts, projected tracks for moving objects of interest). It would be nice to find a design that annotates conditions not only with names, but also with functions for this sort of stuff.

Does anyone have experience with this that they are willing to share?

Comment: Most interesting question I've seen here in quite some time.  Will follow with great interest.

Comment: Something like [Atom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/atom), maybe?

Comment: Yes and no, @Cactus . Implementation in terms of Atom or something like it might be desirable to provide timeliness guarantees in addition to correctness guarantees, but up one or two levels of abstraction how can we structure systems so that in addition to doing the correct thing they can tell us what they are doing, why they are doing it, and what they plan on doing next? How can we modularly support predicting the future?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I would say the "real" answer to your question is that some of things that you are asking for are open areas of research --- in particular I think some of the self-describing features you desire may necessitate some degree of "spaghetti" simply because the problem you are trying to solve is inherently complicated.

That being said, your focus on modularity is exactly the right approach. I would say, take a look at [Keymaera](http://symbolaris.com/info/KeYmaera.html) as I believe it has the features you are looking for despite being in Java. I would also recommend looking at the publications page on the Keymaera website as this should provide you valuable insight to the problem in general.

If you do not like Keymaera's approach you can also look into using Timed Automata which is another direction modeling-wise that should be sufficient for your problem description.

Comment: Very interesting. They seem to be tackling a lot of problems in verification that I would have thought impossible. These problems don't trouble me so much as a hobbyist, but they are certainly interesting when I wear my industrial controls hat. I have lots of new reading to do and a new reason to learn about theorem provers. Thanks. :)

Comment: Also should note that this tackles the much more difficult problem of statically predicting some things about all futures. Suspect the existence of simpler strategies for dynamically predicting some things about some futures with a particle filter. Agree that the self-description problem is to some degree inherently complicated, or to put it another way, may require program structure that isn't the most natural one arising when programs must only convey their dynamic semantics and not the reasons behind them. At the very least you need a grammar with certain required "comments".